# Next JS Error serializing `.dehydratedState.queries[0].state.data.config.adapter` returned from `getServerSideProps

Tags: json, serialization, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-query

I am trying to use `react-query` to fetch data in `getServerSideProps` in Next JS but I keep getting this weird error:

```
Error: Error serializing `.dehydratedState.queries[0].state.data.config.adapter` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/auth/google/callback".
Reason: `function` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

Here is my code:

```
// Packages
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { dehydrate, QueryClient, useQuery } from 'react-query';

// APIs
import { completeGoogleAuth } from '../../../hooks/auth';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()
 
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery('completeGoogleAuth', () => completeGoogleAuth(context.query.code));

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
    },
  }
}

export default function Callback() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data } = useQuery('completeGoogleAuth', () => completeGoogleAuth(router.query.code))

  return (
    <>
      Loading
    </>
  )
}
```

I have tried to use `JSON.stringify(dehydrate(queryClient))` and also used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dehydrate(queryClient)))` but none of them worked.
What can I do?

Comment: are you sure you've wrapped your app with `<QueryClientProvider>` and `<Hydrate>` ?

Comment: @mocherfaoui I have done that

Comment: since you're passing a parameter to the query function you need to make the query key an array, something like `['completeGoogleAuth',context.query.code]`

Comment: Can you share the code for the `completeGoogleAuth` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled across the same error just today, `JSON.stringify(dehydrate(queryClient))` or serializing `dehydrate(queryClient)` by any means won't really work as the object your `completeGoogleAuth` function is returning has function values in the key-value pairs, [here's a picture of the config object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlMxR.png)

And as you know, functions can't be JSON serialized as straightforwardly. Now, what I assume you used(or what I did too) for the `completeGoogleAuth` fetcher function is use Axios as your API client library. I have found that Axios returns objects that can't be JSON serialized. As a solution, I have just used the native JavaScript fetch() API to get API data and the haven't faced any issues since then.

Here's my fetcher function:

```
export const getScholarshipInfoSSR = async (token) => {
   const response = await fetch(
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL + portalRoutes.getScholarshipInfo,
      {
         headers: { Authorization: `JWT ${token}` },
      }
   );

   if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
   }
   return response.json().then((data) => ({ data }));
};
```

Here's the prefetched useQuery invocation:

```
await queryClient.prefetchQuery("portal", () =>
         getScholarshipInfoSSR(token)
      );
```

Comment: it also works for axios,if you just use the `.data` returned from it rather than the whole AxiosResponse.